# Xml using jquery to find siblings from option selected

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have a xml document that contains corporation business names. Here is the tree. 
If the option selected equals the business name's,
find the xml business-name node and get just those siblings: name, phone email.
I have some jquery that pulls the data. I know my code is incomplete, I'm just stuck and trying to figure out the next step.
Not sure if I need to add attributes or redo my xml tree. Just kinda stuck right now. I know my jquery can use something more

________XML_________

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <corporation>
     <business>
        <business-name>cvs</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Dorthorty</name>
           <phone>(999) 999-7777</phone>
           <email>dor@yahoo.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
     <business>
        <business-name>walgreens</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Jon Snow</name>
           <phone>(299) 999-8888</phone>
           <email>jon@gmail.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
     <business>
        <business-name>rite-aid</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Cindy</name>
           <phone>(777) 966-9999</phone>
           <email>cindy@gmail.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
  </corporation>
```

_________HTML___________

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <title> Corps Names</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <select id="corps">
     <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="walgreens" class="letter">walgreens</option>
     <option value="cvs" class="letter">cvs/option>
     <option value="rite-aid" class="letter">rite-aid</option>
   </select>
   <div id="corpsresults">
        <p><span id="name">result</span><br />
            <span id="email">result</span><br />
            <span id="phone">result</span><br />
        </p>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

______Jquery________

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "select" ).change(function () {
     $.fn.retrieveXml = function(data){
        $(data).find('business').each(function(){
            var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();

            // Setup Variables
            var corpData = {
                name: ($('name', data).text()),
                phone: ($('phone', data).text()),
                email: ($('email', data).text()),
                businessname:($('business-name', data).text())
            }
            var webOption = $('select#corps option:selected').val(); 
            var businessName = $('business-name', data).text();

            if (webOption == corpName){
                alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
                $(data).find('business').each(function(){              
                    var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();           
                    $("#name").html(corpData.name);
                });
            }
            else{
                alert("Nope!");
      }
        });
    };

    // Pull data from XML
    $.ajax({
            url: '/business.xml',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            success:function (data) {
                     $.fn.retrieveXml(data);
                    }
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ITV3k61t3svuQGXgc1GV?p=preview):

**HTML:**

```
<select id="corps">
     <option value="">-- select one --</option>
     <option value="walgreens" class="letter">walgreens</option>
     <option value="cvs" class="letter">cvs</option>
     <option value="rite-aid" class="letter">rite-aid</option>
   </select>
   <div id="corpsresults">
        <p><span id="name">result</span><br />
            <span id="phone">result</span><br />
            <span id="email">result</span><br />
        </p>
   </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("select").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'main.xml',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            success:function (data) {
                     retrieveXml(data);
                    },
            error:function(e){alert(JSON.stringify(e));}
    });
        });

    });
    var retrieveXml = function(data){

        $(data).find('business').each(function(){
            var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();

            // Setup Variables
            var corpData = {
                name: ($('name', data).text()),
                phone: ($('phone', data).text()),
                email: ($('email', data).text()),
                businessname:($('business-name', data).text())
            };



            var webOption = $('select#corps option:selected').val(); 
            var businessName = $('business-name', data).text();


                $(data).find('business').each(function(index,item){ 

                    var corpName = $(this).find('business-name').text();
                    if (webOption == corpName){
                    $("#name").html($(this).find('manager > name').text());
                    $("#phone").html($(this).find('manager > phone').text());
                    $("#email").html($(this).find('manager > email').text());
                    }
                });
        });
    };
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <corporation>
     <business>
        <business-name>cvs</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Dorthorty</name>
           <phone>(999) 999-7777</phone>
           <email>dor@yahoo.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
     <business>
        <business-name>walgreens</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Jon Snow</name>
           <phone>(299) 999-8888</phone>
           <email>jon@gmail.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
     <business>
        <business-name>rite-aid</business-name>
        <manager>
           <name>Cindy</name>
           <phone>(777) 966-9999</phone>
           <email>cindy@gmail.com</email>
        </manager>
     </business>
  </corporation>
```

Comment: Your awesome! Thank you for your help! It works how I wanted it to.

Comment: Okay last thing and I have again hit a wall yet again. When a user selects a corporation from the drop down, the name, phone number, email and cc all appear correctly and change when a different option is selected. 

Now I want to incorporate a button for a "mailto:"" link using the values from email and cc. I created variables for the href link. 
( just a note: I'm still learning jQuery)

Now when I select an option, I want it to display a button for emailing the individual; it show three "Email Us"  links (my three corporation options) instead of just one.

Comment: Then when I click the button it shows only one cc address not two, and my subject line gets cut off or doesn't get added. 

Also the button values don't change from the first option selected. So if I change the the option selected,  the name and phone changes, but not the variables for email and cc in the link.

I couldn't figure out how to fork your plunker, (never used plunker before) so I just created a new one. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/WrQO7WNQc7YkcWehsKyf?p=preview